# Test if string end with .html | .html | .json

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a javascript regular expression to test if a string is a valid URL pointing to a `.html`, `.htm` or `.json` resource.

I tried

```
validUrl = new RegExp('(\.html)|(\.htm)$','g');
```

and like this, but did not succeed :( Then i tried

```
validUrl = new RegExp('(.*\.html|.*\.htm|.*\.json)$','i');
```

and this one seems to work, but i'm not convinced that this is correct. Can someone ensure me? :)

Thanks

Comment: `\\ ` instead of `\ ` when creating a regex from a string. The `\ ` in string literal syntax begins an escape sequence, so you need to escape it to pass the actual character to the `RegExp` constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't create constant regexes with the `RegExp` constructor, as that would require double-escaping the backslash in the string literals. Instead, use a regex literal:

```
validUrl = /(.*\.html|.*\.htm|.*\.json)$/i;
```

Now the `\.`s do actually match dots.

You can further shorten this to `.*\.(html?|json)$`, and actually you don't need to match the `.*` to test the suffix, so you can just use

```
validUrl = /\.(html?|json)$/i;
```

Comment: You can simplify this regex to `/\.(html?|json)$/i`

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight I would better go for `/\.(?:html?|json)$/i`

Comment: Sorry for using the grace period, I didn't think you would comment that fast :-)